# Will a mixture of acrylic and oil stains dry?

Tags: deck, staining

I mistakenly mixed acrylic and oil stains.  While difficult to apply, it does look nice.  Will it dry?

Comment: Its likely the oil penetrated and the acrylic wiped off.

Answer (score 1):

I would scrape off as much possible (with grain, avoid digging) with card scraper (cabinet scraper).  Then wipe down with mineral spirits on a clean rag.  Let dry several days and start over.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will dry in about a day but the bigger problem is that it will peel in a short amount of time. If you can clean it off with paint thinner you should